# Code for cron to delete posts that contain specific expression (e.g. "unable to fetch" every 30 minutes

Tags: plugin-development, code

Please does anyone know a code that can automatically delete wordpress posts that contain a specific phrase?  I want to execute it in a cron to delete such posts at regular intervals say 30 minutes

Comment: this can be done with wp-cron, read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Comment: But what about the code itself?  One still needs a code that will be fired by the cron.

Comment: Have Bulk delete, can help >> https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/